# What is the best structure to store grouped rows of data in VB

Tags: vba, data-structures, vb6

I have this data structure:

```
Category  Product  Group  RequiredAmount StockAmount
```

Sample Data

```
A   A   1   10  5
A   B   1   10  10
A   C   2   20  10
A   D   3   30  40
B   E   1   10  15
B   F   2   20  20
```

I want to store it in a collection of a sort, while being able to:

- Access it by **Category** and then by **Product**.
- Keep the **items order** as entered, not sorted alphabetically.
- Change **Amounts**.

It will handle around 100 items.

I initially used a Dictionary for categories, holding a Collection of 1-dimensional arrays, with the product as key.

The main problem is changing the amounts, as changing items in a collection requires adding and removing them, which changes the items order.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would recommend to use a custom class for your data structure... See also [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60504/building-a-better-collection-enumerable-in-vba)...

Comment: For a small list, an array of structures seems good enough.

Comment: @PeterSchneider It's a nice implementation, but it's using a collection, which brings me back to my problem with changing the values without changing the collection. As far as I know if it's an object stored in the collection, the items are returned as copies and not by reference.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a 2 field recordset (you can save it to disk). Make yours' 6 fields and include a line number field that you can use to sort back to original order. Then you can sort and filter it how you want.

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = CSng(SortKey)
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
              .Sort = "SortKey ASC"
              .Filter = "SortKey > 5" 
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```